# libiconv.2.dylib not found

Tags: macos, macports

I get this error on my Mac OS Lion when I use gcc make:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
./configure.sh: line 364: 18386 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $QTDIR/bin/qmake "$SRCDIR/$product.pro"
qmake failed
```

Note: I installed Macports in my machine. This used to work before, is this a known issue with MacPorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the built in libiconv by selecting your target, going to the Build Phases tab and adding it to the link libraries and frameworks build phase.

as a general rule if you are missing linker symbols you can look up the symbol in your project and see what header they are from, and you can then usually figure out the appropriate library or framework.

in this case it tells you what library it is expecting...

you will want to use the built in version for a dynamic library, because with default linker flags, if this built product were to get moved to another computer it would try to resolve the symbols at run time in that location, and crash.